# Update a Select with onchange of other Select in Code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I there, I’m a newbie on CI and I’m having a problem:

On my view page , I have two select boxes on a form and I want to update one select box(items) with data from database after change selection on other select box(category). Does anyone tell me the better way to do this?

there's the code

```
<select name ="category">
    <option id = "y" value="0">--Select--</option>
    <?php foreach($records2 as $r) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$r->cat_id?>"><?=$r->cat_name?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<select name="items">
    <option value="0">Indiferente</option>
</select><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to make [AJAX calls](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) to retrieve the new set of data on every change of selection.

Or, if the amount of data isn't too huge, you can preload all the items for all categories and replace the selector accordingly on every change.

Comment: i dont know how to use ajax here ... can you do it for me ?

Comment: Sorry, no, we don't do homeworks here, but you can tell what problems you're having and what you've tried and everyone will gladly help.